# jQuery Cycle2 to resize images to fit div, but only horizontal images

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

HY!
Is there any way to resize images who are `800px X 600px` to fit conteiner size, but image who are `600px X 800px` to stay normal. I'm using `jQuery Cycle2` for page for accomodation and user can insert images via CMS. So there will be all kind of resolutions and I wona to horizintal images to strech, but vertical images to not.

Comment: Can you give me a tip?

Comment: Please provide some code what you have already tried.

Comment: I didn't try yet, I wonna know is it posible an hope to get guidence for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was pretty simple, this is my code now!

```
#Slider img{    
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add more css:

1. remove width=100% include img tag.
2. Add css:

   .cycle-slide > img {
       height: 600px;
       width: 800px;
   }

done!